# How do things heat one another?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, combustion

For example, how does a gas stove heat a metal pot?

A combustion reaction between the gas and the air takes place, and this releases energy due to new chemical bonds being formed.

Do the atoms in the metal pot absorb these photons, which then excites the atoms' electrons and creates kinetic energy within the atoms (thus, heat)?

Or, are the atoms in the combustion reaction just moving around so fast that they're bumping into all the atoms of the metal pot, generating kinetic energy?

Comment: You already have the gist of it in your latter suggestion. Every time the microscopic phenomena behind combustion and heat transfer are brought up, I can't help but link [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3pYRn5j7oI) [pair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITpDrdtGAmo) of amazing clips by Richard Feynman discussing how it works in simple terms. Understanding flames at that level makes them even more beautiful!

Comment: In short, *conduction*, *convection* and *radiation*.